# Spring doesn't autowire @Configurable when running Dropwizard integration test during maven build

Tags: spring, aspectj, dropwizard, surefire, aspectj-maven-plugin

I'm using Spring's @Configurable to autowire a bean constructed with 'new' in a Dropwizard application. I have an integration test that uses the DropwizardAppRule to bring up the application and am using the aspectj-maven-plugin for compile time weaving.

When I make build and run the integration test from IDEA the bean is wired as expected and the test passes.

When I run 'mvn clean install' the bean is NOT wired and the test fails with a NullPointerException.

When I run 'mvn clean install -DskipTests' and start the application the bean is wired correctly.

My question is why does it fail during 'mvn clean install'?

The aspectj-maven-plugin is running during the process-sources phase so the classes should be instrumented before the integration tests run:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <configuration>
      <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
      <aspectLibraries>
        <aspectLibrary>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </aspectLibrary>
      </aspectLibraries>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>process-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
          <goal>test-compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

If I decompile the class I can see that it has indeed been instrumented.

If I put break point in the @Autowired setter and run the integration test from IDEA I can see that the class is being wired by Spring.

It doesn't break in the setter at all when running 'mvn clean install'.

Replacing @Autowired with @Resource doesn't help.

I have a Spring configuration class that has @EnableSpringConfigured. My best guess is that the DropwizardAppRule isn't using the correct Spring configuration although the other spring components are being managed correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

*edit*

I've also tested both default surefire (maven 3.2.5) and with:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out but a little more context is required to explain the problem. The @Configurable was being instantiated in an enum like so:

```
public enum Day {
    MONDAY(new MyConfigurableObject()),
    ...
}
```

Unit and integration tests were run together and the unit tests were instantiating the enum before a spring context was available. Because enums exist in a static context, the unwired enum was then used by the integration test.

The solution is to split up unit and integration test execution. I did this using the maven-failsafe-plugin like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>it/**</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>it/**</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```